# React.js: JSON request not rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**CODE:**

```
var React = require('react');
var User = require('./User.jsx');

var LeaderBoard = React.createClass({

    users: [],

    componentDidMount: function () {    
      var url = 'https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/alltime'
      var that = this;

      fetch(url)
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
          throw new Error("Bad response from server");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        that.setState({ users: data });
      });
    },

    render: function() {

        var usersLeaderboard = this.users.map(function(item) {
            return <User key={item.id} img={item.img} username={item.username} recent={item.recent} alltime={item.alltime} />;
        });

        return (
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Avatar</th>
                        <th>Username</th> 
                        <th>30 Days</th>
                        <th>All Time</th>
                    </tr>
                    {usersLeaderboard}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    } 
});
```

---

**SITUATION:**

I am following the FreeCodeCamp curriculum and trying to create a leaderboard with React. Sadly, not all the data renders and I have no errors in the terminal or the Chrome dev tools console.

**PROBLEM:**

This is what renders on my screen:

[image]

No users appear :/

What have I done wrong ?

P.S.: New to React, started learning.

Comment: Instead of `this.users.map` try `this.state.users.map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to updated the `LeaderBoard` component as you are using `this.setState({ users: data })` to set the component state with the user data, but you didn't defined state object with `users` key. You can do it like this:

```
var LeaderBoard = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
   return {
     users: [],
   };
  },

  ...other code
});
```

Second thing is that in the render method you need to to get the users from `state` object like this:

```
render: function() {
  var usersLeaderboard = this.state.users.map(function(item) {
      return <User key={item.id} img={item.img} username={item.username} recent={item.recent} alltime={item.alltime} />;
    });

    return (
     ...other code
    );
}
```